# Выбор типа хранилища и способа хранения часто меняющихся данных

Tags: архитектура, nosql, sql

Здравствуйте!

Думаю над тем, как организовать хранение данных в одном потенциально highload проекте, решил посоветоваться. Задача такая: есть список "кандидатов" (~20 штук), есть люди, которые ставят бал каждому (за один раз). Нужно выводить текущий рейтинг кандидатов, т.е. после каждого голоса нужно пересчитывать ~20 чисел. Какие есть варианты:

1. Просто берем PostgreSQL и сохраняем голоса пользователей в таблице. Расчет рейтинга происходит в коде приложения, и кешируется.
2. Использовать опять же реляционную базу данных, но кроме сохранение голосов пользователей сразу же в определенной таблице хранить пересчитанный рейтинг. Для пересчета рейтинга использовать очередь сообщений, или делать это по крону.
3. Первый способ, но использовать NoSQL решение.
4. Второй способ, но использовать NoSQL решение.

Я склоняюсь к NoSQL базе данных и кешированию расчета рейтинга, без денормализации. Как бы поступили вы?

Спасибо!

Comment: А зачем пересчет делать в коде, а не в самом PgSQL? У вас там очень сложная математика? У него встроенные агрегатные функции такие, что фору дадут многим программам. Не говоря про аналитические запросы.

Comment: Пересчитывать можно и в PgSQL, но думаю это не суть важно, если кешировать результат.

Comment: При таком малом объеме данных, как проще (с учетом обеспечения надежности) так и делайте.

Comment: Хайлоад это сколько в цифрах?

Answer (score 1):

Немого непонятно, как у Вас расчитывается рейтинг. Возможно - относительно других параметров: значит, берется много данных из базы и для просчета прогоняется в скрипте? Если так, то думаю лучше делать все вычисления в самой базе. Теперь про базу. Ребята правильно говорили, что у Вас мало пользователей и в случае небольшого числа голосующих можно использовать только nosql решение (например, redis умеет сохранять данные на диск). Пересчет в таком случае будет возможен только в скрипте.

P.S: Приведите алгоритм (теорию только) как будет осуществляться подсчет и хранение рейтинга. Может умные ребята подскажут, как переделать даталогическую модель или Вы получите более конкретный ответ.